# App is crashing because of getRunningTasks()

Tags: android, crash

I have written the following code in a service but my application immediately craches. I have tested the code in the main activity and it works fine, but when I write this code in a service, it crashes. Specifically second line is making it crash.

```
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(2);
```

Comment: Why don't you include your logcat? Meanwhile, do you have the `GET_TASKS` permission in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lacking the `GET_TASKS` permission, and you would then see a `SecurityException` when invoking `getRunningTasks()`. As you're not catching the exception, your app will crash.

Comment: is there any way to prevent the exceptoin? or add a if condition?